# JAVA: Does static attributes of remotely called classes remain in memory?

Tags: java, web-services, static, jersey

For instance, imagine I got this class that uses `Jersey API`:

```
package com.k19.restful.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 

@Path("/helloworld") 
public class HelloWorldResource {

      static int number;

      @GET 
      @Produces("text/plain") 
       public String showHelloWorld() { return "Hello world!"; } 
}
```

When I access it's URL, it prints "Hello world!" at the screen.

But my doubt here is: what about that `number`? Does it remains in memory after the response is returned? Or it's destroyed with the rest of the class?

Comment: Try using it for two different requests, changing it on the first. You will get your answer on the second request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables are initialised when the class first loads, and then remain in memory until the class is garbage collected  (usually not until the JVM exits). So in your case, yes, any state change to the `number` field will be retained for all future requests.

Comment: No. They remain in memory until the class is garbage-collected, which can precede JVM exit.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Although of course in the majority of cases the class won't get garbage collected until the app exits. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The value is a class variable.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

So after loading by this class loader the default value will be 0. And will remain in the memory for the whole application life time.

The class instance itself will constructed with every request. This resource explains that.
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2587

If you would define  the resource as a @Singleton.
Then you could skip static literal.

```
package com.k19.restful.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 

@Path("/helloworld") 
public class HelloWorldResource {

      int number;

      @GET 
      @Produces("text/plain") 
       public String showHelloWorld() { return "Hello world!"; } 
}
```

And still the value would be shared, between request. 
Which is not a good idea because its not thread safe.